# Fatal exception occured

Tags: java

I have a pretty good size project I'm working on here and I was adjusting one part and now I'm getting this errer box that pops up when I try and run the code.  It was working before and the only are that I changed was "CREATE CONTRACTORS".  The error is either going to be in that section, or all the way at the bottom, I think.  I am using Eclipse to run the code and after I run it I not only get that box to pop up, but a message at the bottom of the code that says: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main Exception in thread "main"

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class test extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
private JTabbedPane jtabbedPane;
private JPanel General;
private JPanel Pools;
private JPanel HotTub;
private JPanel Customers;
private JPanel Contractors;

JTextField lengthTextPool, widthTextPool, depthTextPool, volumeTextPool,
lengthTextHotTub, widthTextHotTub, depthTextHotTub, volumeTextHotTub;

JTextArea NameTextCustomers, ExistTextCustomers;


public test(){
setTitle("Volume Calculator");
setSize(300, 200);

JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
topPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
getContentPane().add( topPanel );

createGeneral();
createPools();
createHotTub();
createCustomers();
createContractors();

jtabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
jtabbedPane.addTab("General", General);
jtabbedPane.addTab("Pool", Pools);
jtabbedPane.addTab("Hot Tub", HotTub);
jtabbedPane.addTab("Customers", Customers);
jtabbedPane.addTab("Contractors", Contractors);
topPanel.add(jtabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
              }

/*        GENERAL        */

public void createGeneral(){
    General = new JPanel();
    General.setLayout( null );

    JLabel DateLabel = new JLabel("Today's Date");
    DateLabel.setBounds(10, 15, 150, 20);
    General.add( DateLabel );
    JFormattedTextField date = new JFormattedTextField(
            java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            date.setEditable(false);
            date.setBounds(90,15,150,20);
            General.add(date);

            JButton Exit = new JButton("Exit");
            Exit.setBounds(20,50,80,20);
            Exit.addActionListener(this);
            Exit.setBackground(Color.white);
            General.add(Exit);
                                     }
/*        CREATE POOL        */

public void createPools(){
    Pools = new JPanel();
    Pools.setLayout( null );
JLabel lengthLabelPool = new JLabel("Length of pool (ft):");
    lengthLabelPool.setBounds(10, 15, 260, 20);
    Pools.add( lengthLabelPool );
lengthTextPool = new JTextField();
    lengthTextPool.setBounds(180, 15, 150, 20);
    Pools.add( lengthTextPool );
JLabel widthLabelPool = new JLabel("Width of pool (ft):");
    widthLabelPool.setBounds(10, 40, 260, 20);
    Pools.add( widthLabelPool );
widthTextPool = new JTextField();
    widthTextPool.setBounds(180, 40, 150, 20);
    Pools.add( widthTextPool );
JLabel depthLabelPool = new JLabel("Average Depth of pool (ft):");
    depthLabelPool.setBounds( 10, 65, 260, 20 );
    Pools.add( depthLabelPool );
depthTextPool = new JTextField();
    depthTextPool.setBounds(180, 65, 150, 20);
    Pools.add( depthTextPool );
JLabel volumeLabelPool = new JLabel("The pool's volume is:(ft ^3");
    volumeLabelPool.setBounds(10, 110, 260, 20);
    Pools.add( volumeLabelPool );
    volumeTextPool = new JTextField();
    volumeTextPool.setBounds(180, 110, 150, 20);
    volumeTextPool.setEditable(false);
Pools.add(volumeTextPool);

JButton calcVolumePool = new JButton("Calculate Pool Volume");
    calcVolumePool.setBounds(20,250,180,20);
    calcVolumePool.addActionListener(this);
    calcVolumePool.setBackground(Color.white);
    Pools.add(calcVolumePool);

JButton Exit = new JButton("Exit");
    Exit.setBounds(220,250,80,20);
    Exit.addActionListener(this);
    Exit.setBackground(Color.white);
    Pools.add(Exit);
                       }

/*        CREATE HOT TUB        */

public void createHotTub(){
    HotTub = new JPanel();
    HotTub.setLayout( null );
JLabel lengthLabel2 = new JLabel("Length of Hot Tub (ft):");
    lengthLabel2.setBounds(10, 15, 260, 20);
    HotTub.add( lengthLabel2 );
lengthTextHotTub = new JTextField();
    lengthTextHotTub.setBounds(180, 15, 150, 20);
    HotTub.add( lengthTextHotTub );
JLabel widthLabelHotTub = new JLabel("Width of Hot Tub (ft):");
    widthLabelHotTub.setBounds(10, 40, 260, 20);
    HotTub.add( widthLabelHotTub );
widthTextHotTub = new JTextField();
    widthTextHotTub.setBounds(180, 40, 150, 20);
    HotTub.add( widthTextHotTub );
JLabel depthLabelHotTub = new JLabel("Average Depth of Hot Tub (ft):");
    depthLabelHotTub.setBounds( 10, 65, 260, 20 );
    HotTub.add( depthLabelHotTub );
depthTextHotTub = new JTextField();
    depthTextHotTub.setBounds(180, 65, 150, 20);
    HotTub.add( depthTextHotTub );
JLabel volumeLabelHotTub = new JLabel("The Hot Tub's volume is:(ft ^3");
    volumeLabelHotTub.setBounds(10, 110, 260, 20);
    HotTub.add( volumeLabelHotTub );
    volumeTextHotTub = new JTextField();
    volumeTextHotTub.setBounds(180, 110, 150, 20);
    volumeTextHotTub.setEditable(false);
    HotTub.add(volumeTextHotTub);

JButton calcVolume = new JButton("Calculate Hot Tub Volume");
    calcVolume.setBounds(20,250,180,20);
    calcVolume.addActionListener(this);
    calcVolume.setBackground(Color.white);
    HotTub.add(calcVolume);

JButton Exit = new JButton("Exit");
    Exit.setBounds(220,250,80,20);
    Exit.addActionListener(this);
    Exit.setBackground(Color.white);
    HotTub.add(Exit);
                       }
/*        CREATE CUSTOMERS        */

public void createCustomers(){
    Customers = new JPanel();
    Customers.setLayout( null );

    NameTextCustomers = new JTextArea();
    NameTextCustomers.setBounds(10, 10, 350, 150);
    NameTextCustomers.setLineWrap(true);
    Customers.add(NameTextCustomers);

    JButton Exit = new JButton("Exit");
    Exit.setBounds(30,170,80,20);
    Exit.addActionListener(this);
    Exit.setBackground(Color.white);
    Customers.add(Exit);

    JButton AddCustomers = new JButton("Add Customer");
    AddCustomers.setBounds(130,170,120,20);
    AddCustomers.setBackground(Color.white);
    Customers.add(AddCustomers);

    JButton Refresh = new JButton("Refresh");
    Refresh.setBounds(260,170,80,20);
    Refresh.setBackground(Color.white);
    Customers.add(Refresh);

    ExistTextCustomers = new JTextArea();
    ExistTextCustomers.setBounds(10, 200, 350, 60);
    ExistTextCustomers.setLineWrap(true);
    Customers.add(ExistTextCustomers);

}
/*        CREATE CONTRACTORS        */

public JPanel createContractors(){ 
    final JTextArea contArea = new JTextArea(6, 30); 
    final JTextArea contMessage; 
    JButton addContractor = new JButton("Add Contractor"); 

    addContractor.setMnemonic('a'); 

JPanel contPanel = new JPanel(); 
contArea.setText("Select Add Contractor to add contractor. Select Refresh to refresh this pane."); 
contArea.setForeground(Color.orange); 
contArea.setLineWrap(true); 
contArea.setWrapStyleWord(true); 
JButton contRefButton = new JButton("Refresh"); 
contMessage = new JTextArea(2, 30); 
contMessage.setLineWrap(true); 
contMessage.setWrapStyleWord(true); 

addContractor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{ 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{ // action if button is used 
new Contractor("Contractor"); 
}// end actionPerformed()//end action performed 
}); // end performed action 

contPanel.add(contArea); 
contPanel.add(addContractor); 
contPanel.add(contRefButton); 
contPanel.add(contMessage); 
contRefButton.setMnemonic('R'); 

contRefButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{ 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{ 
contMessage.setText(""); 
try
{ 
File contOpen = new File("contractor.txt"); 
FileReader contAreaIn = new FileReader(contOpen); 
contArea.read(contAreaIn, contOpen.toString()); 
contMessage.setText("The file exists and can be read from."); 
} 
catch (IOException e3) 
{ 
contMessage.setText("The file can't be read." + e3.getMessage()); 
} 
} 
}); 

return contPanel; 
} 

class Contractor extends JFrame 
{ 
private String[] states = { "AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", 
"FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", 
"MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", 
"NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", 
"TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY" }; 
private JComboBox StateList = new JComboBox(states); 
private JTextField NameText = new JTextField(25); 
private JTextField AddressText = new JTextField(25); 
private JTextField CityText = new JTextField(25); 
private JTextField ZipText = new JTextField(9); 
private JTextField PhoneText = new JTextField(10); 
private JTextField PopMessageText = new JTextField(30); 
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 

private AddContButtonHandler addContHandler = new AddContButtonHandler(); 

public Contractor(String who) 
{ 
popUpWindow(who); 
} 

public void popUpWindow(final String who) { 

final JFrame popWindow; 
popWindow = new JFrame(who); 
popWindow.setSize(425, 350); 
popWindow.setLocation(100, 100); 
popWindow.setVisible(true); 
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

Container A = new Container(); 

popWindow.add(A); 

A.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 

JPanel Name = new JPanel(); 
JPanel Address = new JPanel(); 
JPanel City = new JPanel(); 
JPanel SZP = new JPanel(); 
JPanel File = new JPanel(); 
JPanel Message = new JPanel(); 

Name.add(new JLabel(who + "Name")); 
Name.add(NameText); 
Address.add(new JLabel("Address")); 
Address.add(AddressText); 
City.add(new JLabel("City")); 
City.add(CityText); 
SZP.add(new JLabel("State")); 
StateList.setSelectedIndex(0); 
SZP.add(StateList); 
SZP.add(new JLabel("Zip")); 
SZP.add(ZipText); 
SZP.add(new JLabel("Phone")); 
SZP.add(PhoneText); 
JButton addwho = new JButton("Add" + who); 
addwho.setMnemonic('A'); 
JButton close = new JButton("Close"); 
close.setMnemonic('C'); 
JButton deleteFile = new JButton("Delete File"); 
deleteFile.setMnemonic('D'); 
File.add(addwho); 
File.add(close); 
File.add(deleteFile); 
        PopMessageText.setEditable(false); 
        PopMessageText.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER); 

Message.add(PopMessageText); 
    A.add(Name); 
    A.add(Address); 
    A.add(City); 
    A.add(SZP); 
    A.add(File); 
    A.add(Message); 

deleteFile.setToolTipText("Delete File"); 
addwho.setToolTipText("Add "+ who); 
close.setToolTipText("Close"); 

if (who == "Contractor") 
    addwho.addActionListener(addContHandler); // registers listener 

close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    NameText.setText(""); 
    AddressText.setText(""); 
    CityText.setText(""); 
    ZipText.setText(""); 
    PhoneText.setText(""); 
    PopMessageText.setText(""); 
    popWindow.dispose(); 
                                          } 
                   }); 

deleteFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
PopMessageText.setText(""); 
if (who == "Contractor") { 
    File file = new File("Contractor.txt"); 
boolean contFileDeleted = file.delete(); 
if (contFileDeleted) { 
    PopMessageText 
    .setText("Contractor file deleted"); 
               } else { 
                       PopMessageText 
                       .setText("Error deleting file"); 
        } 
                         } 
                                        } 
                         }); 
}

class AddContButtonHandler implements ActionListener { 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent addContHandler) { 
int StateIndex; 
try { 
File file = new File("Contractor.txt"); 

boolean success = file.createNewFile(); 

if (success) { 
   PopMessageText 
    .setText("Contractor.txt file created file added"); 
                            } else if (file.canWrite()) { 
    PopMessageText 
    .setText("Writing info. to Contractor.txt, file added"); 
                            } else { 
                              PopMessageText.setText("Cannot create file: Contractor.txt"); 
       } 
try { 
FileWriter fileW = new FileWriter("Contractor.txt", true); 
fileW.write(NameText.getText()); 
fileW.write(","); 
fileW.write(AddressText.getText()); 
fileW.write(","); 
fileW.write(CityText.getText()); 
fileW.write(","); 
StateIndex = StateList.getSelectedIndex(); 
fileW.write(states[StateIndex]); 
fileW.write(","); 
fileW.write(ZipText.getText()); 
fileW.write(","); 
fileW.write(PhoneText.getText()); 
fileW.write("\r\n"); 
fileW.close(); 
PopMessageText.setText("Contractor has been added!"); 

FileReader fileR = new FileReader("Contractor.txt"); 
BufferedReader buffIn = new BufferedReader(fileR); 

buffIn.readLine(); 
buffIn.close(); 
   }

catch (IOException e1) { 
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1.getMessage(), 
"Error", 2);
                       }
    NameText.setText(""); 
    AddressText.setText(""); 
    CityText.setText(""); 
    ZipText.setText(""); 
    PhoneText.setText(""); 
} catch (IOException e1) { 
                         }

}
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
JButton button = (JButton)event.getSource();
String buttonLabel = button.getText();
if ("Exit".equalsIgnoreCase(buttonLabel)){
Exit_pressed(); return;
    }
    if ("Calculate Pool Volume".equalsIgnoreCase(buttonLabel)){
        Calculate_VolumePool(); return;
    }
        if ("Calculate Hot Tub Volume".equalsIgnoreCase(buttonLabel)){
            Calculate_VolumeHotTub(); return;
    }
                                             }
private void Exit_pressed(){
System.exit(0);
                           }
private void Calculate_VolumePool(){
String lengthStringPool, widthStringPool, depthStringPool;
    int lengthPool=0;
    int widthPool=0;
    int depthPool=0;
lengthStringPool = lengthTextPool.getText();
widthStringPool = widthTextPool.getText();
depthStringPool = depthTextPool.getText();
if (lengthStringPool.length() < 1 || widthStringPool.length() < 1 || depthStringPool.length() < 1 ){
    volumeTextPool.setText("Enter All 3 Numbers"); return;
    }
        lengthPool = Integer.parseInt(lengthStringPool);
        widthPool = Integer.parseInt(widthStringPool);
        depthPool = Integer.parseInt(depthStringPool);
            if (lengthPool != 0 || widthPool != 0 || depthPool != 0 ){
                volumeTextPool.setText((lengthPool * widthPool * depthPool) + "");
    } else{
        volumeTextPool.setText("Enter All 3 Numbers"); return;
      }
                               }

private void Calculate_VolumeHotTub(){
    String lengthStringHotTub, widthStringHotTub, depthStringHotTub;
        int lengthHotTub=0;
        int widthHotTub=0;
        int depthHotTub=0;
    lengthStringHotTub = lengthTextHotTub.getText();
    widthStringHotTub = widthTextHotTub.getText();
    depthStringHotTub = depthTextHotTub.getText();
    if (lengthStringHotTub.length() < 1 || widthStringHotTub.length() < 1 || depthStringHotTub.length() < 1 ){
        volumeTextHotTub.setText("Enter All 3 Numbers"); return;
        }
            lengthHotTub = Integer.parseInt(lengthStringHotTub);
            widthHotTub = Integer.parseInt(widthStringHotTub);
            depthHotTub = Integer.parseInt(depthStringHotTub);
                if (lengthHotTub != 0 || widthHotTub != 0 || depthHotTub != 0 ){
                    volumeTextHotTub.setText((lengthHotTub * widthHotTub * depthHotTub) + "");
        } else{
            volumeTextHotTub.setText("Enter All 3 Numbers"); return;
          }
                                   }
public void main(String[] args){
JFrame frame = new test();
frame.setSize(380, 350);
frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}
}
```

Comment: I recommend you to put your code to more files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your main method to class "test" (from Contractor) and change declaration to static. Btw. regarding to java naming conventions class name should start with capital letter

Change your 469 line:

```
public void main(String[] args) // bad
```

To:

```
public static void main(String[] args) // good
```

Comment: Can you show me which lines of code you're talking about.  I am fairly new to coding and it has taken me forever to get this far.  Are you referring to the main at the bottom?  Thanks

Comment: @Mike, see the first answer posted - you only have one main() - that's the one you should update :)

Comment: When I do that it says :The method main cannot be declared static; static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type

Comment: @Mike, yes, this is because you didn't move your main to class "test", cut your all method main (with body) to the last line - just before the last } (this means "top level")

Answer (score 5):

main() has to be static.......

EDIT: I suggest you fix your formatting with an auto-formatter in your IDE.  That would make the incorrect placement of your main method even more obvious.

Comment: Peter, that's far too much time between OP and solution :)

Comment: I don't know why everybody like voteup only persons with high reputation - other people can have right too :)

Comment: @smas, I posted first which tends to get more votes. Later answers were more detailed.

Comment: @smas, because his answer was first and correct it got upvotes.  adding more information can result in upvotes but when all of the pertinent information is there, I tend to not upvote a different answer just because it has more (unnecessary) info.

Comment: but in this situation only changing to static is not correct answer

Comment: The answer was correct but often there is far more than one thing which can or should be done to improve/fix the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void main(String[] args){
```

Method main is supposed to be static! :-)